# Rails環境構築でのエラー: ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

AWScloud9によるrails環境構築でrails db:createをする際にこのようなエラーが出てしまいます。
解決方法についてご教授いただけると幸いです。

**エラーコード**

```
ec2-user:~/environment/RailsReactApp (master) $ rails db:create
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:234:in `build_db_config_from_string': '{ 　socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock }' is not a valid configuration. Expected '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' to be a URL string or a Hash. (ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError)
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: 
　socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: RailsReactApp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: RailsReactApp_test
    
production:
  <<: *default
  database: RailsReactApp_production
  username: RailsReactApp
  password: <%= ENV['RAILSREACTAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このエラーが出たときは config/database.yml の書き方が間違っていることが多いです。

```
　socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

↑おそらくこの行が間違っています。質問文通りの内容をお使いなら、最初のインデントの部分が全角スペースになっていて半角スペース 2 つになっていません。このため正しい YAML として読み込まれていないではないかと推測します。